# libgit2sharp: Status(path) returning "NewInIndex" on rename when "RenameInIndex" expected

Tags: c#, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

When I rename a file, I run a `GetStatus()` method that visually updates the status of my files after they get added/checked out/ reverted/renamed/etc. When I rename a previously checked out file it returns NewInIndex rather than either RenamedInIndex or RenamedInWorkingDir status.

Here is my method:

```
public Tuple<SourceControlStatus, LockStatus> Status(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                var existingPath = path;
                //finds an existing path so we can still get the status of deleted files (repo.Discover will fail if the path does not exist)
                while (!File.Exists(path) && !Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    existingPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(existingPath);
                }

                var repoPath = Repository.Discover(path);
                using (var repo = new Repository(repoPath))
                {
                   var status = repo.RetrieveStatus(path);
                   return new Tuple<SourceControlStatus, LockStatus>(GetStatus(status), LockStatus.None);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            return new Tuple<SourceControlStatus, LockStatus>(SourceControlStatus.Checkin, LockStatus.None);
        }
```

Can anyone help me understand what I need to do to get it to accurately return the right status? Or is the fix to simply, if the item returns "NewInIndex", check the status of the entire repo, and then examine the list of renamed files, and see if any match the one in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rename detection when you are examining the status of a single path.

Since renames are computed by diffing the `HEAD` to the index (to determine what's renamed in the index), and by diffing the index to the working directory (to determine what's renamed in the working directory), there is no explicit change type for a file that is renamed.  Additionally, the status information is not cached, it is recomputed for every invocation.

Finally, for efficiency, when you request the status for a single path, the rest of the repository is *not* examined.  (Otherwise, repeated `GetStatus(string path)` operations would become quadratic.)  This means that there is no ability to scan other files that could be candidates as the "other half" of that rename operation.

If you want rename information, the best thing to do here is to `GetStatus()` on the entire repository and then examine the paths you're interested in from the returned results of that status.